# give names to values in a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

not sure if this is possible but it should. i want to have a matrix which elements have names just like you can do in a vector like this:

```
v = 1:10
names(v) = LETTERS[1:10]
```

result:

```
 A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J 
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

I've tried to create a matrix and use the same sintax:

```
m = matrix(v, ncol=2, nrow=5)
names(m) = letters[1:8]
```

but the result is not what i hoped for.
result:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    3    5    7    9
[2,]    2    4    6    8   10
attr(,"names")
 [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j"
```

I dont want it to be two separated entities. is there a way to do this without any libraries? or at all?
Thank you

Comment: `rownames()` and `colnames()`?

Comment: If you want your `2` to have its own distinct value, then ... no, R isn't going to show that to you. The names in a `matrix`/`array` are assigned to columns and rows, as Limey suggested.

Comment: The code you have used already achieves what you want, I think.  `m["b"]`, for example, gives the answer `2`.

Comment: no, sorry but i don't want to name my columns nor my rows  but the elements inside it. to be more precise i want to share what i'm trying to do. i'm trying to simulate a kind of solitary where you have 36 cards of a 40 cards deck in front of you in what basically is a matrix 4*9. since the numbers in the matrix are cards they all have suits. i want to have the suit of the card(element inside matrix) to have its suit. you may know the term "suit" as "seed"

Comment: i have overcame this issue creating a parallel matrix that contain the suits. But if there is a better solution i'd like to know it